# How do I set up my combo box with my pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I am pretty new to VBA, but I want to do is create a Combo Box to interact with my pivot table. So the items in the combo box would be the Rows from the Pivot Table fields. I want to select the field that I want, and it would only show that.

How would I start the code out? Or where can I find info to start?

This what I got so far

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim pt As Pivot Table
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim cbo As ComboBox

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

For Each pf In pt.RowsFields
   If pf.Name <> "Values" Then
        pf.Orientation = xlHidden
   End if
Next pf
If cbo = "customer" Then


Activesheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Customer").Orientation = xlRowField

End Sub
```

The code currently not working right now, but I hope you guys see the idea. So the options going to be customer, location, and product.

Comment: When you create a pivot table, the row headers are filterable by default -- the little black triangle button.  Does this not accomplish what you need already?

Comment: So in the pivot table now, there is let say "Product" in the Rows and "Revenue: in the Values. But I want to change the "Product" field to now "Customer" without going back to the pivot table option and drag the "product" out and "Customer" in. I hope that I am making sense.